# CSS: Creating fixed header and footer while having dynamic context using flexbox

Tags: html, css

I am trying to set a fixed header and fixed footer where the inner content container can be any size and it doesn't effect the header/footer size.  I am a bit stuck and can't tell if I am using `flex-basis` incorrectly here for the `.container div` styling ?

```css
.container {
  display: flex;  
  flex-direction: column;
}
.container div {
  flex-basis: 50px;
}

.header {
    background: red;
}
.content {
    background: pink;
}
.footer {
    background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="header"></div>
    <div class="content"> 

    <div class="footer"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Dear @Ricardo: I have tried to answer your question. Please have a look. Hope this is what you were looking for :) Even, if you do not set the height then using f`lex:1` on `.content` will make sure your content grows with the text:)

Comment: thanks Imran!  I didn't think of using `justify-content: space-between` to keep them apart vertically, thanks!  I just posted another answer as well after playing around with it...does my solution work as an option ?

Comment: Hi friend :) I have mention using `flex:1;` as well in my answer. which actually is a short form for... `flex-grow:1;` `flex-shrink:1;` `flex-bases:auto;` So I have it covered my friend as well... Please check my last updated answer :)

Comment: cool, thank you!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set a `min-height` to your `container` and use `justify-content:space-between;` Also, use `flex:1` on `.content` so that it takes the avaible space in between :)

**Here is the full code:**

```css
.container {
  display: flex;  
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height:100vh;
  justify-content:space-between;
}
.container div {
  flex-basis: 50px;
}

.header {
    background: red;
}
.content {
    background: pink;
  flex:1;
}
.footer {
    background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="header"></div>
    <div class="content"> 

    <div class="footer"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just came up with this using `flex-grow: 1` on the content section to take up all the inner space.  Is this a viable option?:

```css
body {
  background: grey;
}
.container {
  display: flex;  
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}
.header {
    background: red;
    flex-basis: 50px;
}
.content {
    background: pink;
    flex-grow: 1;
}
.footer {
    background: green;
    flex-basis: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="header"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
    <div class="footer"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look, this is the usual solution to fixing *header* and *footer* to **flex**.

Where for `.header` and `.footer` you give a fixed height - `flex-basis: 50px`, but you give the `flex: 1 0 auto` in `.content` to accommodate this container in **free space**.

Also, add this to your css to exclude unnecessary indentation of the `body` tag, as well as rule `box-sizing: border-box`:

```
body {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

And still not an important point. Set height for `.container` container - `min-height: 100vh`.

```css
body {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.container {
    display: flex;  
    flex-direction: column;
    min-height: 100vh;
}

.header {
    background: red;
    flex-basis: 50px;
}

.content {
    background: pink;
    flex: 1 0 auto;
}

.footer {
    background: green;
    flex-basis: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="header"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
    <div class="footer"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi mate! May I know how is your answer different from mine ;) `flex-shrink:0` Right :) ?

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit confused but may be this is what you want:

```css
        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        .container {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
        }
        .container div {
            flex-basis: 100vh; /* No need to use that in all DIVs, just the content */
        }
        .header, .footer {
            position: fixed;
            width: 100%; /* whatever you want */
            height: 8vh; /* whatever you want */
        }
        .header {
            top: 0;
            background: red;
        }
        .content {
            background: pink;
            height: 100vh;
        }
        .footer {
            bottom: 0;
            position: fixed;
            background: green;
        }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header"></div>
  <div class="content"></div>
  <div class="footer"></div>
</div>
```